# Logic in JsViews css-tag

Tags: css, jsrender, jsviews

I am trying to put logic in a `css-width` in a `data-link` in jsViews. The two following approaches did not work:

```
{{for Items}}
    ...
    <td id="show-keys" data-link="css-width{~root.ShowKeys ? '200px' : '400px'}">
```

or

```
{{for Items}}
    ...
    <td id="show-keys" data-link="css-width{:~keysWidth()}">
...

<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    var app = {
        ...
        helpers: {
            showKeys: function () {
                //debugging shows that this never gets fired
                return app.ShowKeys ? '400px' : '100px';
            }
```

How do I appropiatly base a css-value on a property so that it changes dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle that shows a few variants: http://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/GZPvZ/

Your first expression missing a :

```
data-link="css-width{~root.ShowKeys ? '200px' : '400px'}"
```

should be

```
data-link="css-width{:~root.ShowKeys ? '200px' : '400px'}"
```

For the second approach, using a helper, apart from the naming of the helper (I think you meant it to be `keysWidth` - as @BKimmel points out) - you need to declare the fact that it is a computed observable with a dependency on `~root.showKeys` - which you do like this:

```
function keysWidth() {
    return app.showKeys ? '400px' : '100px';
}

keysWidth.depends = "~root.showKeys"; // or you can write ... = [app, "showKeys"]
```

Alternatively you can not declare the dependency, but pass it in as an argument:

```
data-link="css-width{:~keysWidth3(~root.showKeys)}"
```

Helpers can be declared globally, or passed in with the link call.

See the jsfiddle for details...

***Update:*** There are now some new samples that cover CSS and class binding. There is a [tutorial sequence on data-linking](http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link), which includes [this page](http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link/class) on data-linking class, [this](http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link/toggle) on on toggling class, and [this one](http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/data-link/css) on linking to CSS attributes.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I have only tried the first [inline] approach (which is what I wanted.  
I can try the second one later.

Comment: I added some links to new samples, above

Answer (score 0):

At a glance here, I notice two things;

1. For the second setup, I wouldn't expect that to work as written... your helper function is called showKeys, but in the template you are calling a function called keysWidth... maybe that was just a transcription mistake, but it definitely won't work like that.  Change the names so they match (case-sensitive, as always in JS).
2. Make sure your helpers are actually getting loaded... e.g. $.helpers({helperfunction: function() {...}}) ... sometimes that can cause issues.

Comment: Is there an efficient way to check for missing helper functions?