# Data-Link to CSS background-image using a helper function not render

Tags: jsviews

I have a template which renders a background image to CSS within a `<div>` like this
`style="background-image: url({{>~facilityImagePathDisplay(#data)}})"`

Visual Studio doesn't like this and it's not a big deal but I wanted to see if there was a proper way to do this. I read through the documentation. Other stack questions and the below was created based off of the docs. This specifically links to all the docs [Logic in JsViews css-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405789/logic-in-jsviews-css-tag)

`<div class="tile-image" data-link="css-background-image{:~facilityImagePathDisplay(#data)}" >`

The above statement outputs exactly this to the div. `<div class="tile-image" data-link="css-background-image{:~facilityImagePathDisplay(#data)}">` so it looks like it's not firing the helper function and rendering anything at all. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you are running the `link()` method of JsViews, or simply the `render()` method of JsRender.

Your first version will works in both cases, but is simply rendering the CSS style.
The second version would only be used if you are running the `link()` method of JsViews - for data-binding etc. (So the background image could be dynamically updated if you data-binding triggers a new value).

For the data-link version, you need to makes sure the helper is returning a string that is not just `"someUrl"`, but `"url(someUrl)"` - to provide the correct CSS data url syntax. In that case, the following should work:

```
data-link="css-background-image{:~facilityImagePathDisplay(#data)}"
```

Alternatively you can have the helper return just the `"someUrl"` string, but then include the `"url("` and `")"` strings in the template:

```
data-link="css-background-image{:'url(' + ~facilityImagePathDisplay(#data) + ')'}"
```

Comment: I am using the `link()` and I used the second example you had which worked so I appreciate the help and explanation with this.